# system suddenly closed when found the similar face

Tags: python, face-recognition

i'm doing my first face recognition project

i have the face image data which will be encoded, so this is my directory

```
./Desktop/dataset/amber_heard/image.jpg
./Desktop/dataset/jokowi/image.jpg
```

and this is my code:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
known_face_encodings = []
known_face_names = []

os.chdir("./dataset")
for file in glob.glob("**/*.jpg"):

    images = face_recognition.load_image_file(file)
    images_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(images)[0]
    known_face_encodings.append(images_encoding)
    print(images_encoding)

    dir_list = next(os.walk('.'))[1]
    known_face_names.append(dir_list)
```

i'm using the code from [link](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam_faster.py), i just change comparison code to:

```
        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)     
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index] and matches[best_match_index] < 0.3:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        face_names.append(name)

process_this_frame = not process_this_frame
```

i use `os.walk()` to get my subdirectory from directory `dataset`, if the system detect similar faces from my dataset, the system will show the name based on my subdirectory name.

but my problem is, when my webcam detect the similar face. my system suddenly closed. is there anything wrong with my code? i really need the solution. Thanks in advance ! and pardon my english.

Comment: parts of the code are clearly missing, i don't see any recognition from the camera

Comment: i'm using the code from https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam_faster.py.

Comment: why don't you open an issue on github? author might help you faster

Comment: Does the original code work if you don’t change the comparison code?

Comment: yes, but when i add the os.walk function. it didn't run @barny

Comment: So therefore you need to debug what you have changed (i.e. using `os.walk()` to find the faces to match) because apparently the face recognition code you are using works. What error message do you get - include the full traceback

Comment: if `dir_list` is a list of directory names below `dataset`, why append that list to the list `known_face_names` for every `file` that you load? Do some debugging or just add some print statements, check what on earth your variables contain. Have a separate play with os.walk - you're probably better off using it instead of `glob.glob` - choose one or the other. Personally I would have the jpg file the name of the person in it, rather than calling them all image.jpg, then you don't even need to maintain the `subdirectory/image.jpg` setup.